# bootstrap 4 Page design is not appearing as excepted

Tags: php, bootstrap-4

I have designed a page using bootstrap 4. But it is not appearing according to my design. Below the code of CSS and JS files that I used. Also shared the excepted appearance and wrong appearance.

```
<!-- Link CSS  // -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css">
<link href="../css/bootstrap-select.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/bootstrap-multiselect.css"/>
<link href="../css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">

<!-- Link JS   -->
<!--<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>-->
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.21.0/moment.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.js" integrity="sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-multiselect/0.9.13/js/bootstrap-multiselect.js"></script>
<!--<script src="../js/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>-->
<script src="../js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js"></script>
<!--<script src="../js/bootstrap-multiselect.js"></script>-->
<script src="../js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="../js/bootstrap-select.js"></script>
<script src="../js/ajax.js"></script>
<!-- multiselect based on dropbox -->
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<!-- Graph Chart  -->
<script src="https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Creating-A-Live-Editable-Table-with-jQuery-Tabledit/jquery.tabledit.js"></script>
```

Below the excepted Appearance
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fzyhd.png)

the Wrong appearance
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IoFJB.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably it's because the order of the CSS elements.

The latest you reference on the HTML document is the one who has more priority.

Try to first load the bootstrap base CSS and then the others:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link href="../css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css">
<link href="../css/bootstrap-select.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/bootstrap-multiselect.css"/>
```